# Why response failed to load when use get() in query in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-6

I tried to get data from db having the particular id . The code is as follows :

```
$obj = new Products();
       $res= $obj->select('*')->where('track_id',$trackId)->orderBy('shipping_date', 'desc')->get();
```

But I am getting error as 'Failed to load Response Data'.

I have no idea why this error occurs. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eloquent model, you can directly use class name to fetch records in following manner.

```
$obj = App\Product::where('track_id',$trackId)
         ->orderBy('shipping_date', 'desc')
         ->get();
```

Reference: [Retrieving Model](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)

Comment: I tried it.. But not working... Actually the problem occurs only when I use get(), If I use first() its working.

Comment: can you try with `->all()` without where clause one time, to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: normally this error comes on client side, can you use `try ...catch` to see the actual error in php code.